# PHP. Date. Change format

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, type-conversion

How can I change the date, for example,

2012-08-03 to the timestamp 1344024896 using PHP?

And the inverse?

```
$date='2012-08-03'
$stampDate=?
```

Comment: [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). It's in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to timestamp:

```
$date='2012-08-03';
$stampDate=strtotime($date);
```

reverse:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', $stampDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

With two functions:

```
strtotime($date);
```

and

```
date('Y-m-d', $stampDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `strtotime` to get a timestamp from the date string (it will work with `Y-m-d`).  `date('Y-m-d', $timestamp)` is the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-08-03');
$stampDate = $dt->getTimestamp();
```

And you can even convert timezones

```
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
```

and format the date:

```
echo $dt->format('d.m.Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (time) 
like:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2012/12/12');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the variables in the question:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$date = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can change from other format date..

```
$date1='21 May 2015';
$newdate = date_format(date_create_from_format('d M Y', $date1),'Y-m-d'); 
echo $newdate;
```

Output Will **2015-5-21**

Comment: This is not the date manipulation requested in the question. Instead of posting an identical answer on multiple questions, please answer the question that is being asked in the original post.